# Working updated example C# for azure file storage StorageV2

Tags: azure-storage

Using the [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files) provided by MS for Azure File storage works for StorageV1 - it does NOT work for accessing files via file service (c#) on StorageV2.

I've filed a defect on git and posted on the tech forum (no update on git, incomplete response on tech forum) - has anyone been able to make this work with StorageV2?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with ZRS - the new azure storage creation page finally shows that ZRS works only with blobs..

[image]